# ServiceStack Ormlite issuing Sqlite specific command

Tags: sqlite, ormlite-servicestack

I am running Ormlite against a sqlite database.  Love it.
I am adding and deleting lots of records and find that the database does well with an occasional Vacuum command.
How can I issue this around the ormlite api?

TIA

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [db.ExecuteSql()](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite#typed-sqlexpressions-with-custom-sql-apis) API to execute Custom SQL, e.g:

```
Db.ExecuteSql("INSERT INTO page_stats (ref_id, fav_count) VALUES (@refId, @favCount)",
    new { refId, favCount })
```